# How to defiine Quarkus Heap Space Size

Tags: quarkus, graalvm-native-image, quarkus-native

I have a Quarkus application that transforms large sets of data. At some point I always get an Out Of Memory Exception. I think when I am running the application in "Java Mode" the JVM xmx  flag should work to give Quarkus more memory. Is that correct?

How can I set the memory of the application when running as native image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running the native binary, `-Xmx` is used the same way as in JVM mode.

See [this](https://www.graalvm.org/reference-manual/native-image/MemoryManagement/#java-heap-size) for more details.